# How to write protect a flash memory sector in STM32F407

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, flash-memory

I have been working with the STM32F407. When the device is flashed for the first time, I manually write some very important information to flash memory. I use the following function to write to the flash memory:

```
#define SERIAL_OFFSET 0x80E0000

void FLASH_write_serial_number(uint32_t serial_number) {

    taskENTER_CRITICAL();

    uint32_t write_test = serial_number;

    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    FLASH_WaitForLastOperation(2000);

    if(HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, SERIAL_OFFSET, write_test) == HAL_OK){
        printf("FLASH_WRITE_OK\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("FLASH_WRITE_FAIL\n");
    }
    FLASH_WaitForLastOperation(2000);
    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    FLASH_WaitForLastOperation(2000);
    taskEXIT_CRITICAL();
}
```

I noticed that sometimes the data dissapears from the flash memory. Reading back from it returns:
4294967295
Which means that is clear.

In order to ensure the data does not dissapear from the flash memory, I decided to activate write protection for the whole sector that I use (sector 11). I do this via STM32CubeProgrammer:

[image]

That seemed to fix my problem and the data no longer dissapears. However, it is very inconvenient to run STM32CubeProgrammer for each device and disable that checkbox. I was hoping if there is an easier way to achieve the same results from the code. Is there a function that would allow me to activate write protection for a particular section? I have tried looking up online but didint manage to find any results

Comment: Check the return value of FLASH_WaitForLastOperation.

Comment: When I initially write the value to the flash memory, everything seems to be fine. After I write a serial number, I read back to confirm that everything is ok.

After that, I no longer write to flash memory, I only read back from it (I put read function to my initial post). Then at some point (it might be couple of hours or couple of days, the value just dissapears from the flash memory). I can check the return value of that function when I am writing to the flash but after that I never write to it again

Comment: Sorry, I misread the whole question.  Yes, you can set the write protection  programmatically; read the manual section about option bytes.  However, you should still check what part of your code or programming process is performing an erase.

Comment: If you never write to it again, the data can't be lost. It's lost if and only if you actually erase it somewhere. You have to find where you perform an unexpected erase. Right now, you're solving the symptom, but not the cause of the problem. In theory, you wouldn't ever need to write-protect, if you do everything right (check flash memory location for 0xFFFFFFFF, if so, write, else, do nothing, something of this sort)

Comment: Thanks! Il go through the code very carefully to see if I can find where else the flash memory is being accessed.